# Does anyone know this stock iOS color?

Tags: ios, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-development

Hi I am building a hybrid mobile app and wish to use this color for an alert. However, I cannot seem to get the color right along with the opacity. Does anyone know how to achieve this extremely subtle blur/transparency of this volume alert background? Thanks!

[image: screenshot with volume alert]

Comment: use blur effect uiview

Comment: it is not transparency, it is blur and/or vibrancy

Comment: The name of the component is UIBlurEffectView.

Comment: thanks! Might any of you know how to achieve this in standard CSS? All I have found is filter:blur() which only blurs along lines (so on a single color only the edges)